# Plot every 2nd point in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to plot every 2nd point in Excel using VBA and not involving use of extra columns? Thanks.

Comment: You will have to give us enough information to understand what you're trying to achieve, else we can't help. See this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are plotting points to a line graph.  Correct?  If that's the case I wouldn't use VBA at all.  Just make a custom range name selecting every other point.  If you explain your situation a little better I might be able to help.